# Можно ли рассчитать угол rotateY и значение perspective?

Tags: html, css, transform, rotate

Хочу сделать то, что на фото

Вопрос: Можно ли каким-то способом рассчитать угол `rotateY` ИЛИ все это делается "на глаз", подгоняя под пример?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Второй вариант быстрее. Поскольку для остального определить это квадрат или прямоугольник не представляется возможным

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться онлайн генератором     [CSS3 Perspective Playground](https://codepen.io/mburakerman/pen/wrZKwe)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбрано:

perspective(250px) rotateY(42deg);

```html
<style>
img {
  width:150px;
  margin:40px;
}
img.first {
  transform:perspective(250px) rotateY(42deg);
}
img.last {
  transform:perspective(0px) rotateY(0deg);
}
</style>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" class="first">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/DGAOsPz.png" class="last">
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте инструмент Pixel Perfect. Приложите изображение к сайту и смещайте его пока не получите нужный результат